# Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, z-index

I have a linear layout which consists of imageview and textview , one below another in a linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ... >
 <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
     android:layout_weight="0.8" 
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 </ImageView>
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TextView>
```

Some rules might be missing , this is to give an idea , how layout looks.
I want another small text view of say 50dip in length and width , placed over the imageview, by "over" I meant z-index more than imageview , I want to place this , in the center and above(overlapping) the imageview.

I want to know how can we place one view above the other, with varying z-index (preferably in linear layout) ?

Answer (score 320, accepted):

You can't use a LinearLayout for this, but you can use a [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html). In a `FrameLayout`, the z-index is defined by the order in which the items are added, for example:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="My Label"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

In this instance, the TextView would be drawn on top of the ImageView, along the bottom center of the image.

Comment: Yeah I did it using frame layout itself after going through documentation. Thank you.

Comment: Is there an advantage of using FrameLayout instead RelativeLayout for this?

Comment: FrameLayout doesn't relate to other views in the group, it just layers them in regard to the parent. RelativeLayout is more for positioning relative to other items.

Comment: by using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries,I am able to show part of previous and next page as shown in image above,but now I don't want to show sharp edges on images.I want them to blur towards edges..please guide me on how can i use z-index for achieving the same

Comment: use match_parent, not fill_parent

Comment: FrameLayout is the key. I've even used this to draw things over map views and in some situations, though I have no idea why, it works where a relative layout does not.

Comment: Hi kcoppock my mobile (hdpi) doesn't respect z-order in frame layout, but i have an other (xhdpi) and respect this order, do you know why do this? Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: And it is applicable for the elements in the DrawerLayout also. This will be helpful while using the two list views in the Navigation Drawer.

Comment: As of API 21 / KitKat you can now use setZ and translationZ; the FrameLayout hack is no longer needed (finally!).  This should be the preferred answer for modern 5.0+ development: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29703860/358578

Comment: Not the actual solution for me, but with a little modification it solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 202):

Give a try to `.bringToFront()`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29

Comment: can we use this in xml files too?

Comment: I was looking for something such to bring my view to change itz zindex during translation animation.

Comment: Could u find a solution for translation animation?

Comment: bringChildToFront() just changes the index of the View inside its parent

Comment: Take care about Nepster's comment. Because bringChildToFront() changes the index, the items' layout order is changed (changing x and y coordinates). It does not only change the z order, as one might think.

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks. This is especially required if we are toggling the views on and off programtically in between

Comment: killer answer, your unorthodox-ed and not like other fools out here, who gave the same conventional(copy cats) answers... your true legend

Comment: this screws the whole layout order

Comment: bringToFront or make sure that the layer/frame you want to be drawn is added first at framelayout index:  
 rootLayout.addView(shadow);
        rootLayout.addView(viewPager,0);//to make dropshadow effect visible , draw viewpager at least layer

Answer (score 72):

RelativeLayout works the same way, the last image in the relative layout wins.

Comment: Unless you use elevation, then you also need the largest value in that.

Comment: This question was asked and answered before elevation existed. 
Using elevation won't fix the issue if your app has a minSdk less than Lollipop (on pre-lollipop phones the layout will look wrong if you rely on just elevation) -  you still have to pay attention to the order of the layout.  You are right though, that if you use elevation on the bottom component - you definitely need to have at least the same or higher on the top.

Answer (score 31):

## Changing the draw order

An alternative is to change the order in which the views are drawn by the parent. You can enable this feature from ViewGroup by calling [setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(boolean)) and overriding [getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildDrawingOrder(int,%20int)).

### Example:

```
/**
 * Example Layout that changes draw order of a FrameLayout
 */
public class OrderLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private static final int[][] DRAW_ORDERS = new int[][]{
            {0, 1, 2},
            {2, 1, 0},
            {1, 2, 0}
    };

    private int currentOrder;

    public OrderLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true);
    }

    public void setDrawOrder(int order) {
        currentOrder = order;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
        return DRAW_ORDERS[currentOrder][i];
    }
}
```

### Output:

Calling `OrderLayout#setDrawOrder(int)` with 0-1-2 results in:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you call setDrawOrder(i) in the activity's onCreate()?  If I have 6 widgets in my xml, do I need to initialize each row of DRAW_ORDERS with an array of 6 numbers (0-5)?

Comment: @JohnWard the layout shown above is solely for example purposes, you can define your own behaviour in getChildDrawingOrder().

Comment: here's related post with much clear code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524162/framelayout-in-reverse

Answer (score 28):

I solved the same problem by add `android:elevation="1dp"` to which view you want it over another. But it can't display below 5.0, and it will have a little shadow, if you can accept it, it's OK.

So, the most correct solution which is @kcoppock said.

Comment: Don't know why this is so underrated answer.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `view.setZ(float)` starting from API level 21. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing) you can find more info.

Comment: This should now be the preferred answer for API 21 / KitKat / 5.0 or higher.  The old frameLayout hack is thankfully no longer required.  Personally I don't understand the difference between setZ and translationZ, but the latter is an attribute and worked beautifully for me.  Thanks!

Comment: For the previous apis you can use ViewCompat#setZ() too.

Comment: @AliYucelAkgul if you look at the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setZ%28android.view.View,%20float%29), you can see  `Compatibility: API < 21: No-op `. So I think it will not work

Comment: @VadimKotov, I have tried in my app and it just works.

Comment: @AliYucelAkgul well, that is strange. Maybe a mistake in the docs? Are you 100% sure it is working for API < 21?
I have an idea that it can change order of views for the previous APIs, but no fancy stuff like elevation, etc..

Comment: @VadimKotov, I just pushed my code but let me check it again.

Comment: I would assume translationZ would translate from the current z index, ie: z index = 3, so translationZ = 4 makes z = 7, whereas setZ just sets the z index.

Comment: since `setTranslationZ()` and `setZ()` were added in API 21, I'm gonna have to wait on using them *for a few years* because the current min API level is 17 for the app (and I suspect for most apps) I'm working on.

Answer (score 8):

Try this in a RelativeLayout:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.SetZ(float z);
```

It works for me.

Comment: You should explain a bit better. For instance where would you put this code?

Comment: Well, I put it in OnCreate() method. Each image added has an z index of preference over the ones added before. I mean, through the z index I can change the position of the next behind the previous.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to use LinearLayout. Just set the marginTop of your previous element to the corresponding negative value, and make sure the element you want on top is after the element you want below in your XML.

```
<linearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ... >
<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
 android:layout_weight="0.8" 
 android:layout_width="0dip"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
</ImageView>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/description"
android:layout_marginTop="-20dip"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK you cannot do it with linear layouts, you'll have to go for a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

Comment: RelativeLayout does not extend frameLayout, are you sure that it will work?

Comment: It will. You can use any of FrameLayout or RelativeLayout. Each having different ways of placing child views. Refer to the docs to know more about those layouts.

Comment: this is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

I use this, if you want only one view to be bring to front when needed:

```
containerView.bringChildToFront(topView);
```

**containerView** is container of views to be sorted, **topView** is view which i want to have as top most in container.

for multiple views to arrange is about to use setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true) and overriding getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding the View programmatically, you can use `yourLayout.addView(view, 1);`

where `1 is the index`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a RelativeLayout:

example XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_offer_close_outline"
        app:tint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:translationZ="999dp" />
```

example java:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.SetZ(float z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:transformZ`. It works also with LinearLayout.