# Overlapping ImageView in RelativeView

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

As my code below shows, I've two ImageView that I would like to overlap but the bigger is systematically put below the smaller one, both is android:layout_alignParentTop set "true", I thought that would lead to an overlapping but Android keeps dislaying them one below the other.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeStars" android:src="@drawable/background" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerInside" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
            />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeLogo" android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="220dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="2dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Nota 1 : I do not want the first one to be set as a background of the relative view.
Nota 2 : I should add that this Relative Layout is put inside a ScrollView.

Comment: So you're problem is right now they overlap...? And what it is you *want* them to do?

Comment: If one is behind the other... in what way are they not overlapping?

Comment: It's below, not behind : that's exactly my problem.

Comment: add the view first which you want behind then add the other one which you want in front that's all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeStars"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeLogo"
        android:layout_width="220dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I removed all of you're different layout_* tags and it works fine. Naturally all children will overlap each other by positioning themselves at the top left in a `RelativeLayout`. You're extra tags were confusing not only me but likely the parser. Copy paste the above code and make changes incrementally next time! :)

Comment: The positionning directives of the RelativeLayout did mess it up. The incremental process works but it's time consuming. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android). A FrameLayout will get the job done, even though you seem very keen on a RelativeLayout. Is a compromise possible for you?