# how to use z-index in android

Tags: android, android-layout

```
  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
  <ImageView android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
   android:background="@drawable/nicetab" 
   android:layout_width="300dp" ></ImageView>
    <TextView
        style="@style/DialogText.Title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="45dip"
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/codeFont" 
        android:textSize="15dip"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

How could I put TextView on ImageView. Is there any way in android to do this, in HTML it is too easy we ara using z-index, but here - no idea

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple way would be to use a `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@drawable/nicetab"
        android:layout_width="300dp" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/DialogText.Title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="45dip"
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/codeFont" 
        android:textSize="15dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The suggested way to do the text view on top of an image view is to use the textview's drawable.

```
android:drawable[Top|Left|Right|Bottom]="@your_drawable_here"

<TextView
    style="@style/DialogText.Title"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="45dip"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/codeFont" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_drawable_from_imageview" 
    android:textSize="15dip" />
```

I'm not sure what you have in your style, so if what is given above doesn't work, try removing the style, or paste the style here, and I'll help you out.