# How to set z index by using some integer values

Tags: android, xml, z-index

I have been working in android for past few months. The problem for me is now related to Z index value. I am having a layout with a textview,edittext and imageview.
 Suppose i have a xml file something like this..

```
 <Layout1>
    <edittext><zindex>3</zindex></edittext>
    <textview><zindex>2</zindex></textview>
    <imageview><zindex>1</zindex></imageview>
 </Layout1>
```

So my question is that am reading this xml file by DOM parser and i want to set the z index value for all these by the values defined in the xml. Now is there any function or property that i can use to do it.
    I have learnt about coding it with xml, but that will make it hardcoded. I want a dynamic display so how do i adjust layout with the zindex values.... HELP PLZ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is no Z-index in android layouts. You'll need to use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout if you need to place elements on top of each other in reverse order.

see [Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android)

Comment: Ok thanks man... I wish android could provide something that can help place z index dynamically...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `view.setZ(float)` starting from API level 21. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing) you can find more info.

Comment: but setZ is used to show elevation, which was not needed.

Comment: Are you sure its not [setTranslationZ](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationZ%28float%29) ?

Comment: look yourself http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setZ(float)