# How does zindex work in android, how can I change the order later

Tags: android, z-index, layer

I have an XML Layout with imageButton and I want add "later" some imageButtons programmatically. Unfortunetly the added buttons cover the XML button. How can I use the zindex? Zindex attribute doesn't exist. I want @+id/btn_surface upper.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="none"
>

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rLayoutss"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="5000px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/repeattile"
        tools:context="com.some.asc.somesystems.SomeActivity"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="5000px"
            android:id="@+id/iw_pcover"
            android:background="@drawable/repeatovertile"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="800px"
            android:layout_height="480px"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/rl_all_hud"
            >


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="105px"
                android:layout_height="106px"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:id="@+id/ll_surface"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="106px"
                    android:layout_height="105px"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_surface"
                    android:background="@drawable/terr_button_surface"
                    />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="94px"
                    android:layout_height="105px"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_surface"
                    android:text="Surface"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-26dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14px"
                    android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:shadowDx="2"
                    android:shadowDy="2"
                    android:shadowRadius="2"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Add imageButton:

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rLayoutss);
    ImageButton largeIcon = new ImageButton(context);
    largeIcon.setImageResource(
         getResources().getIdentifier(PObject.getString("imgsrc"), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80,80);
    lp.leftMargin = 100;
    lp.topMargin = 100;
    largeIcon.setLayoutParams(lp);
    largeIcon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    largeIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    relativeLayout.addView(largeIcon);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set z index by using some integer values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576758/how-to-set-z-index-by-using-some-integer-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add your childView, `largeIcon` in this case you want to use the `ViewGroup.addView(View view, int index)` method. This will allow you to specify which order you want your views to appear in.

For your case, you might want to try: `relativeLayout.addView(largeIcon, 0);`

Comment: relativeLayout.addView(largeIcon, 0); It's work for me! Awesome solution. Thx