# FrameLayout in reverse

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to figure out how to alter the way FrameLayout stacks it's children.

Currently it is newest on top (FIFO). I'd like to change it such that the newest child is on the bottom (FILO). I tried looking through the source code for FrameLayout but I can seem to find any clues on how it stacks it's child elements.

At first I thought `getLayoutDirection()` is what I was looking for but that only pertains to RTL/LTR for accessibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true)` and override `getChildDrawingOrder` with:

```
    @Override
    protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
        return childCount - 1 - i;
    }
```

Please, take a look at [the fork I did from your code](https://gist.github.com/italobb/7921967) and test it.

Comment: You save my dayssssss. I've tried to do animation on several childs inside FrameLayout. But can't get the effect right until found your post! Great thanks!