# Put image above another image in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I m trying to create a layout where there is image which is in background and another image which i m tring put on above of the background image,but the issue is i want to place second image above first one without loosing quality of second image .Now it is bit blur as below in 3rd image:

Here is my 2 Images :

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:

[image]

It looks this way :

[image]

third image is getting bit blur..
is it possible to make more clear image as result .

My Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/intentskip"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@drawable/blank"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/frames_01521" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use a `FrameLayout` such as following:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:focusable="false" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Read [more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and [even more](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/) about `FrameLayout` and you will love it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/background_or_image_bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/frames_01521" />
```

Or you can use **FrameLayout**

[Placing/Overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try using FrameLayout or Fragments. As far I understood it will solve your problem.

Comment: See, what Erix Jiang has suggested. It will help.