# TextView background transparent, but expecting solid color

Tags: android, textview, transparency

In situation below, TextView background should be solid color, but instead i get it transparent somehow.. so on listview scroll, listview content is visible through textview, but it should not.

Here is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/listSection"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:background="#707e89"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:autoText="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/medicationList"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
</FrameLayout>
```

What is wrong here :) ?

[image: transparent TextView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping the two items in your `FrameLayout`. I suspect that the `ListView` is in fact transparent, and your `TextView` is under it.

Some more information is available from this SO question: [Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android)

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I realized it by myself later, but still we can debate about the subject. 
"z-index is defined by the order in which the items are added". So, if TextView is added first, then it should be shown above all other components?

Comment: The last item in the layout is the highest item and vice versa for the first item. Not a whole lot of debate required :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with the color you used for background.

```
<TextView
   android:background="#AARRGGBB" />
```

Above AA is for alpha channel, RR for red, GG for green and BB for blue.
Here is the Hex Opacity Values that you can used for AA:

100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00

Try to change the color according to given format and see still the problem  is happening there.

Comment: That was the first thing i've tried, but if you think about it little longer, "#707e89" is solid color, without transparency included, so you cant make it less transparent as it is now :). See discussion on anwser above (@NasaGeek).