# How can I overlap a button over an ImageView?

Tags: android

[image]

Hello, to achive a view like the image above that has an attached reomve button
i have tried the following xml Linearlayout and setting its background a round image
but to achive proportonate picture It would be better to use ImageView,

Sorry that my english is not so good but i just wanted to ask how can i achive this
by using ImageView in place of LayoutBackground...

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_image_holder"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="0dp" >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/searchGroupButton"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icn_delete"
                        android:onClick="removeImage"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>
             </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Example @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android/4685019#4685019

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with a Relative Layout, just insert the two childs and position the elements as desired:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/yourImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchGroupButton"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icn_delete"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps!

Regards!

Comment: Since nothing is being layed-out relatively to anything, the same effect could also be achieved using `FrameLayout`, with the `ImageView` having a `layout_gravity="center"` and the button not specifying any layout params since views, by default, are in the top left corner. `FrameLayout` will be slightly more efficient at measuring and laying-out than the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: That is a really good comment, indeed is another option but FrameLayout is not very device fragmentation friendly and this is just an example, he might come up with an anchor object or something more complicated eventually...

Comment: thanks,with this solution you made it clear to me the usage of relative Layouts in android

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchGroupButton"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="removeImage"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</FrameLayout>
```