# Resume/bring to top active (but hidden) fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have added 3 fragments to my Activity with

```
String name = "fragment1"; // and ..2 and ..3
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, name);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(name);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The last added (third) Fragment now is visible on top.
Now I want to resume to the first added Fragment. But how?
I can find this Fragment with

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment firstFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment1");
```

If I call `fragmentManager.getFragments()` I still can find all three Fragments.

How to bring `firstFragment` back to top, make it visible again?

Comment: Try `fragment.getView().bringToFront()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7332294/3060087

Comment: Good advice. But after switching between two fragments several times I receive NullPointerException...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **hide** your `2nd` and `3rd` **fragment** and make your `1st fragment` visible. So you'll have the effect that first fragment is shown on top and others are invisible.

**solution:**

Use the `FragmentTransaction's show and hide method`. Firs you need to find all the fragment and call the `FragmentTransaction` to show and hide 2nd and 3rd fragments.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. But is that the only solution? Why is there a method like bringToFront() or resume()? Have I misunderstood the use of fragments?

Comment: @almisoft `bringToFront` are only used for view childs not in fragment. so let say you have relative layout with a lot of child on top of each other you can call `bringToFront` on a child to bring in front(z-axis)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it in my app when I want to switch to `fragment`:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if (fragment.isAdded())
{
    transaction.show(fragment);
}
else
{
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
}
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Note the use of `show`.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up with this:

```
/**
 * @param tag name of the fragment to resume and to bring to top
 * @return true if fragment has been found
 */
private boolean bringFragmentToTop(String tag) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        for (Fragment f : fragmentManager.getFragments()) { 
            if (f == fragment)
                fragmentTransaction.show(f);
            else
                fragmentTransaction.hide(f);
        }   

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```