# Android XML: Showing listview above viewpager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-xml

i want to show `ListView` above `ViewPager` using following code but it shows `ViewPager` without `ListView` above it. I used following `XML` code from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android)

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/wpedenyo_searched_friends_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager></FrameLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

It showing following UI

[image]
Here jassmin is the content of `ListView`. It's showing bellow `Tab` but i want it above all.

Comment: change the height of viewpager to `wrapcontent` and also ensure your list view has items  so that it can have some height

Comment: @Panther doesn't change view after change code

Comment: Try using fixed heights, just to check if both views appear, if you want to divide your screen in 2 or something use `layout_weight`

Answer (score 1):

FrameLayouts are meant to hold a single child.

Try LinearLayout or RelativeLayout as the parent instead.

For example, you could make a vertically oriented LinearLayout parent and have the vertical space split evenly between your ListView and ViewPager like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wpedenyo_searched_friends_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want one or the other child to take up more vertical space, adjust the layout_weights accordingly.

Comment: It makes `ListView` above `ViewPager` but below `Tab`. But want it at top of whole `ViewPager`.

Comment: @user3384985: Your comment is less than clear. Perhaps a simple graphic would explain what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I recently required something like this, Try using AutoCompleteTextView

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
  findViewById(R.id.wpedenyo_searched_friends_list);
     textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```