# Showing one imageview above others?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I want to show one Imageview above other imageview or view. Like below picture.

[image]

To achieve this I wrote code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_restaurent_info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".35"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/frameImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:src="@drawable/demo_pics" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_restaurent_pic"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_search" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- android:background="@color/Orange" -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/restaurent_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Laziz"
                android:textColor="@color/list_restaurent_name_text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/restaurent_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/restaurent_name"
                android:layout_below="@+id/restaurent_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="151 Radford Road, Nottingham, NG7"
                android:textColor="@color/list_restaurent_name_text" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But can't achieve the desired one.

My output looks like below. Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. You need to tweak some code here `

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCake"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_cake" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_laziz"
        android:id="@+id/imgLaziz" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Laziz"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgCake"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLaziz"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLaziz"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="151 Radford Rasd Nott"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is your answer: [Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android)
You can't use a LinearLayout for this, but you can use a FrameLayout. In a FrameLayout, the z-index is defined by the order in which the items are added. Credits to @kcoppock

Comment: i already use FrameLayout. but i am unable to solve the combination of the actual output.

Comment: @shihab_returns What about that second part of your code (I mean that second linear layout)? Problem may be there...

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try Relative layout for it...because by using it you can put android:layout_above="@+id/yourImageIdwhichYouWantToAboveFromAnImage"
i hope by using this your problem being solved.!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) that gives you many [properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) about positioning your views.
So, all you have to do in my opinion, is to change the architecture of your view in order to realign them properly.