# Rajawali transparent background

Tags: android, xml, surfaceview, glsurfaceview, rajawali

I am trying to overlay a `RajawaliSurfaceView` with the Earth Demo-Renderer over the [Google Vision Face Tracker sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker).

I use this to make the background transparent:

```
rajawaliSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

This is the layout file of my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:surfaceview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
      android:id="@+id/preview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
        android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>
    <org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rajawali_surface"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
</FrameLayout>
```

It compiles without a problem, but I do not see the 3d model or the FaceGraphic from the Google Demo project.
I also get this error when trying to preview the layout xml in Android Studio:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onResume(GLSurfaceView.java:562)
at org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView.onResume(RajawaliSurfaceView.java:106)
at org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView.onVisibilityChanged(RajawaliSurfaceView.java:116)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14537)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:232)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:366)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I removed this line (`rajawaliSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);`), hoping to see the 3d scene at least, but nothing changed, I still only see the camera preview.

However, when resuming the app from anywhere I see the rotating earth for the fraction of a second, before the camera preview is started.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android), it should work as I expected it to. What do I have to do?

**UPDATE 2:**
(using [this](https://andrewhague.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/how-to-set-a-transparent-glsurfaceview/) tutorial)

OK - Adding the line `rajawaliSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);` renders the 3d scene on top of my camera preview, but I still have a problem.

Neither

```
rajawaliSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
rajawaliSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

nor

```
rajawaliSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
rajawaliSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

only clear the background of the scene.
I allways get a fully transparent SurfaceView. Any ideas how I can resolve this?

(Apparently the xml error only seems to be a mild anoyance I'll have to ignore.)