# Imageview with textview behind

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, imageview

What I am trying to achieve is the following. [image]

The circle of the left is an ImageView and each of the gray boxes on the left would be a TextView.
As simple as it sounds I am getting stuck and have only been able to achieve the following.

[image]

Here is my my xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:id="@+id/singlerowRL"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/climbing"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#00000000"
         />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/interestone"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/roundshapebackground"
            android:text="Fitness"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/interestfive"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/interestfive" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/interesttwo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/roundshapebackground"
        android:text="Gaming"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interestthree"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/interestthree"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/interestthree" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/interestthree"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/roundshapebackground"
        android:text="Coding"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interestfour"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/interestfour"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/interestfour" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/interestfour"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/roundshapebackground"
        android:text="Traveling"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interestfive"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/interestfive"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/interestfive" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/interestfive"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/roundshapebackground"
        android:text="Shopping"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interestone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put circleImageView at the bottom of Layout not at the top

Comment: It worked! What a silly mistake. Thanks for the help! :) @user2095470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving that circular element from starting of RelativeLayout to just before the ending tag of RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView` after `TextViews`, at the end of `RelativeLayout`.

Alternatively see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android).