# Imageview alignment issue

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I want to achieve my layout with image-view and relative layout as like as picture shows here.

[image]

I tried with this code but not works.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview_ratting"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/4182486/3225001

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me...Provide negative paddingTop equal to half of the size of the imageview .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widget_title_icon"
            android:paddingTop="-70dp"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: this is the image screenshot]

Comment: Why have you taken LinearLayout as root element, if there is only one element in it?

Answer (score 1):

We normally use **FrameLayout** for this case:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_title_icon"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

We can also play with **android:paddingTop="-10dp"** as you like.

See [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) definition:

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child
>   on top.

Hope this will help....

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"` -35dp is the half of your image size (70dp/2) but margin in the reverse direction so use "-" sign.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview_ratting"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

used FrameLayout, using frameLayout you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should use `FrameLayout`. `FrameLayout` provides a layered layout to overlap items in UI. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_title_icon"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Arpan has already proposed a similar answer. He is using padding and margin of both elements, whereas this one uses layout gravity and relative margin of `ImageView`. Doing this will always place the contents in the center of the screen on all devices.

```
ImageView(android:layout_marginBottom) = 0.5 * RelativeLayout(android:layout_height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use [circleimageview](/questions/tagged/circleimageview) and [relativelayout](/questions/tagged/relativelayout) as a child of [framelayout](/questions/tagged/framelayout).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp">
</RelativeLayout>

 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cir_img_ptv"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/cir_img_diameter_ptv"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/cir_img_diameter_ptv"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cir_img_top_margin_ptv"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_user"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                app:civ_border_width="@dimen/cir_img_stroke_ptv"
                app:civ_fill_color="@color/white"
                app:civ_border_overlay="true"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code,

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relCustomerEditProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imgBackground"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relProfile"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_black"></RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relProfile"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgViewProfilePhoto"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/red"></de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hereby,I am attaching screenshot,

[image]

Hope, it helps you!!

Comment: too many layouts to draw, will degrade the performance...not an optimal approach..try with FrameLayout