# textview over another invisible textview, do not repond on click

Tags: android

I have two `TextView` in my android code, one over other. The lower text view do not have `onCLickListener` set but the other `TextView` has, and also lower `TextView` is set invisible. The problem is that the upper text view do not respond on click as long as it is placed over the other text view. Please tell how can I solve this issue? I can not change components' positioning because of some reasons.

Comment: set its visibility to `gone` and see once

Comment: please post your xml code.

Comment: clickable="false" or focusable="false" on the lower TextView should do the trick if it's really your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a z-index problem to me: your invisible view is placed on top of the visible one, which does not receive the click.
The click is received by the invisible one, that does nothing.

I've never experienced that, but you could try to define the visible view after the invisible in your `xml` file.

If it does not work, I believe that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android) can be something that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the textview is gone not just invisible:
Eg.

textview.setVisibility(View.GONE).

This will make the textview leave instead of just making it invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Apply following line on desired `TextView` and then check `onClick` event.

```
yourTextView.bringToFront();
```