# RelativeLayout's Last child doesn't display on top of other child

Tags: android, overlapping

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

The actual result :

[image]

My XML is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/question_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/oval_button"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="X"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/oval_grid_wrong"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I bring the `X` TextView to the front?

Comment: Have you tried ViewGroup.bringChildToFront(View); ?

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android

Comment: @Mayur I haven't, but is there any way we could do this without coding?

Comment: try adding elevation to textview

Comment: Button has default elevation

Comment: Why don't you use `ConstraintLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing button default elevation in your xml

```
<Button
...
android:stateListAnimator="@null" 
....
/>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot!