how to make layout to be in front? androidstudio
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/filterlayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menulayout"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/formenulayout"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"

            >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_button" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gear"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:useMaterialThemeColors="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/materialCardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/menulayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/menulayout"
                app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                app:queryHint="Search here" />

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    </LinearLayout>

Hello, this is my code for my mainacitivty. when i press menu imageButton the menulayout increases in height and it works perfectly except the problem is that becuase menulayout increases in height it causes the toplayout to increase in height as well that i dont want it to do.
how can i make it so when the height is increased for menulayout it will be in front of everything and the top layout stays the same.

instead of wrap content try match_parent

Hello, that will not work because now the layout will be on the whole screen. my xml contains the top layout than in the middle its filter layout that will be visible or gone depends if the button is clicked or not and than at the bottom a recycler view. so making match parent wont work.

if you don't want it to be on whole screen , still don't want to resize , set a constant height

if i set constant height then the expanded part of the menulayout is being cut

i want that expanded part to go over the toplayout, elevation does not work.

You trying something like z-index,

check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android

also tell me if anything work, thanks

i tried framelayout and relativelayout but it still does not work, the expanded part being cut because of other layouts

Have you tried the SetZ()

Unless you've a well explained answer that isn't one liner, you could have put it as a comment

SetZ() is inside the above link I commented
